# "File opened that is not a database file" opening firefox's cookies.sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, cookies

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330142/Cookie-Quest-A-Quest-to-Read-Cookies-from-Four-Pop

I implemented code from the above link to read cookies for Firefox, Internet Explorer, and chrome.  The methods for Internet explorer and chrome both work.  However, sqlite is throwing a connection for the firefox method on `conn.open()` that reads "File opened that is not a database file."  The file is there and everything.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Here are the methods used by firefox that throw an exception:

```
private static bool GetCookie_FireFox(string strHost, string strField, ref string Value)
        {
            Value = string.Empty;
            bool fRtn = false;
            string strPath, strTemp, strDb;
            strTemp = string.Empty;

            // Check to see if FireFox Installed
            strPath = GetFireFoxCookiePath();
            if (string.Empty == strPath) // Nope, perhaps another browser
                return false;

            try
            {
                // First copy the cookie jar so that we can read the cookies from unlocked copy while
                // FireFox is running
                strTemp = strPath + ".temp";
                strDb = "Data Source=" + strTemp + ";pooling=false";

                File.Copy(strPath, strTemp, true);

                // Now open the temporary cookie jar and extract Value from the cookie if
                // we find it.
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(strDb))
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT value FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE '%" +
                            strHost + "%' AND name LIKE '%" + strField + "%';";

                        conn.Open();
                        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Value = reader.GetString(0);
                                if (!Value.Equals(string.Empty))
                                {
                                    fRtn = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Value = string.Empty;
                fRtn = false;
            }

            // All done clean up
            if (string.Empty != strTemp)
            {
                File.Delete(strTemp);
            }
            return fRtn;
        }

private static string GetFireFoxCookiePath()
        {
            string s = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                             Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            s += @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\";

            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(s);
                DirectoryInfo[] dir = di.GetDirectories("*.default");
                if (dir.Length != 1)
                    return string.Empty;

                s += dir[0].Name + @"\" + "cookies.sqlite";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(s))
                return string.Empty;

            return s;
        }
```

Here are the working chrome methods:

```
private static bool GetCookie_Chrome(string strHost, string strField, ref string Value)
        {
            Value = string.Empty;
            bool fRtn = false;
            string strPath, strDb;

            // Check to see if Chrome Installed
            strPath = GetChromeCookiePath();
            if (string.Empty == strPath) // Nope, perhaps another browser
                return false;

            try
            {
                strDb = "Data Source=" + strPath + ";pooling=false";

                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(strDb))
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT value FROM cookies WHERE host_key LIKE '%" +
                            strHost + "%' AND name LIKE '%" + strField + "%';";

                        conn.Open();
                        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Value = reader.GetString(0);
                                if (!Value.Equals(string.Empty))
                                {
                                    fRtn = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Value = string.Empty;
                fRtn = false;
            }
            return fRtn;
        }

private static string GetChromeCookiePath()
        {
            string s = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            s += @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies";

            if (!File.Exists(s))
                return string.Empty;

            return s;
        }
```

Comment: I'm able to copy and open the cookies file with SQLite Command Shell 3.7.17. Your path looks okay. Have you tried this while Firefox isn't running? Are you using the latest version of SQLite?

Comment: Updating my System.data.sqlite.dll did it.  Thanks.  Submit it as an answer if you'd like to.